# Many to Many query on Lucid models, AdonisJs

Tags: sql, many-to-many, lucid, adonisjs-ace

Consider a simple situation of `users` and `subjects` related with a pivot table named `user_subjects`, now if I have to fetch all the users who have opted for a certain subject. What is the best way to achieve this in AdonisJs 5. Following is the solution I found.

```
const subject = await Subject.find(req.params.id);


const users = await subject.related('users').query();
```

There is nothing wrong with the above approach but I think there is an extra query to fetch the entity and then load the relationship. Is there a more optimised way to achieve above?

Also to take the above example a bit further, if suppose `users` are related to `classes` through a pivot table `user_classes`, can that not be achieved using 1 query on Lucid Models and not using Database class?

Comment: https://github.com/adonisjs/lucid/issues/672#issuecomment-825721904